# How do I sort items in a listbox while keeping the other listboxes' data aligned?

Tags: xml, vb.net, arrays, sorting, listbox

I have this XML file from which I'm grabbing all the data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Tabel>
  <Member>
    <Naam>Cruciatum</Naam>
    <Kills>10</Kills>
    <Deaths>2</Deaths>
    <Score>2222</Score>
  </Member>
  <Member>
    <Naam>test</Naam>
    <Kills>123</Kills>
    <Deaths>12</Deaths>
    <Score>12222</Score>
  </Member>
  <Member>
    <Naam>test2</Naam>
    <Kills>159</Kills>
    <Deaths>12</Deaths>
    <Score>2222</Score>
  </Member>
  <Member>
    <Naam>test3</Naam>
    <Kills>159</Kills>
    <Deaths>122</Deaths>
    <Score>222284</Score>
  </Member>
  <Member>
    <Naam>test4</Naam>
    <Kills>15</Kills>
    <Deaths>1229</Deaths>
    <Score>129453</Score>
  </Member>
</Tabel>
```

I got it all to show in 5 different listboxes (1 for each childnode under "Member").

I have this following code to do that.

```
Public Class Rank
    Dim memberNodes As XmlNodeList
    Dim memberNode As XmlNode
    Dim x As Short
    Dim dataNodes As XmlNodeList
    Dim firstinrow As Boolean
    Dim datalist(5) As String
    Dim y As Short

    Private Sub Rank_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        lstView.Items.Clear()
        x = 0
        Dim doc As New XmlDocument()
        doc.Load("C:\Members.xml")
        memberNodes = doc.GetElementsByTagName("Member")
        For Each memberNode In memberNodes
            dataNodes = memberNode.ChildNodes
            y = 1
            For Each dataNode As XmlNode In dataNodes
                datalist(y) = dataNode.InnerText
                datalist(0) = (x + 1).ToString
                y += 1
            Next
            datalist(5) = datalist(4)
            datalist(4) = FormatNumber((datalist(2) / datalist(3)), 3)
            Dim lvi As New ListViewItem(datalist)
            lstView.Items.Add(lvi)
            x += 1
        Next

    End Sub
End Class
```

That code is working fine for now, displaying the full list.
But now I need all the data sorted by the values in the Score column of the listview, so for in the following example: 
[image: Result so far]

I would need the first line to say: "1    test3    159    122    1.303    222284"

Second line the 2nd place on Score, etc.

**Update:**
Instead of seperate listboxes I'm now using 1 listview, as recommended by @SteveDog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of separate list boxes, use a ListView control with the View property set to Details,  or use a DataGridView control.  If you must use separate list boxes like that, you will need to implement the IComparable interface on each class to override the sorting.

Sorting in a ListView control is admittedly a bit of a pain.  It's nice to have it be so flexible, but it's a pain when all you want to do is a simple sort.  First, you need to create a sorter object that implements the IComparer interface.  For instance:

```
Public Class ScoreSorter
    Implements IComparer

    Public Function Compare(ByVal x As Object, ByVal y As Object) As Integer Implements IComparer.Compare
        Try
            Dim xItem As ListViewItem = CType(x, ListViewItem)
            Dim yItem As ListViewItem = CType(y, ListViewItem)
            Dim xInt As Integer = Integer.Parse(xItem.SubItems(5).Text)
            Dim yInt As Integer = Integer.Parse(yItem.SubItems(5).Text)
            Return yInt - xInt
        Catch
            Return 0
        End Try
    End Function
End Class
```

Then you need to set the ListView control's ListViewItemSorter property to a new instance of the sorter object, then tell it to sort, such as:

```
ListView1.ListViewItemSorter = New ScoreSorter()
ListView1.Sort()
```

Comment: I updated the OP, how do I get the last column (Score) to sort in a descending way?

Comment: Awesome :) It works now, thanks :D
(I'ld ask you how I can have it sorted by Score first and then by K/D, but I won't bother you with it :P This is enough for now ^^)

Answer (score 0):

Try this (not tested):

```
Dim sortedNodes = memberNodes.OrderBy(Function(n) n.ChildNodes(3))
For Each memberNode In sortedNodes
   ...
Next
```

You will need to have a `Imports System.Linq`.

Comment: Changed `n.ChildNodes(4)` by `n.ChildNodes(3)` and changed code to VB (sorry).

Comment: No problem :P I'm trying out SteveDog's idea first though, with the Listview control. I've never used one of those so I might aswell learn how to use that now :)

Comment: Yes that's probably a better approach. The `ListView` control looks like the right pane of the Windows Explorer. The `DataGridView` looks more like a Excel or Access table.